# Seaborn heatmap to .pdf incredibly slow. Is this normal?

Tags: pdf, matplotlib, seaborn

Trying to save some experimental data to file I noticed that when trying to save NxN sized heatmaps the execution would never complete. Investigating further it appears to be due to the .pdf extension. If I use, for example, .png it's extremely fast.

Minimum reproducible example:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sbn

N=200
THE_FIGURE = plt.figure(figsize=(8.27, 6), dpi=300)
ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
sbn.heatmap(np.random.uniform(1, 20, (N, N)), ax=ax)
THE_FIGURE.savefig('image.pdf', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.1)
```

This slowdown becomes noticeable even when N = 100. 
N=1000 isn't even happening.
Is this normal? and how can I fix it

thanks!

Comment: This is probably due to the fact that the conversion to PDF is done by using vector graphics. This has the advantage that the PDF can be zoomed and the graphics appear crisp, but the disadvantage that the file size might get bigger than with a bitmap graphic and that it needs more processing power to convert and then display.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It makes sense that for larger grids saving the pdf takes longer than saving the png. This can be seen in the following graph, where time for saving the pdf and png as a function of the number of tiles along one axis (`N`) is shown (solid lines). We can also look at the filesize of pdf and png, where some similar behaviour is oberved (dashed lines).

[image]

Find here the code for reproduction. Running this on my computer takes ~1:10 minutes.

```css
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import time
import os

def f(N, form = "pdf"):
    t0= time.time()
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8.27, 6), dpi=300)
    ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
    sns.heatmap(np.random.uniform(1, 20, (N, N)), ax=ax)
    fig.savefig('image.'+form, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.1)
    t1 = time.time()
    plt.close(fig)
    s = os.path.getsize('image.'+form)
    return t1-t0,s

ns = [5,10,15,20,25,30] + range(40,210, 20)
pdf = []
png = []

for i,n in enumerate(ns):
    pdf.append(f(n, form="pdf"))
    png.append(f(n, form="png"))
    #print i, n

pdf = np.array(pdf);png = np.array(png)
plt.figure()    
plt.plot(ns, pdf[:,0], label="pdf")
plt.plot(ns, png[:,0], label="png")
plt.xlabel("N")
plt.ylabel("time [s]")
ax2 = plt.gca().twinx()
ax2.plot(ns, pdf[:,1]/1000., label="pdf (filesize)", ls="--")
ax2.plot(ns, png[:,1]/1000., label="png (filesize)", ls="--")
ax2.set_ylabel("filesize [kByte]")
plt.gcf().legend(ncol=2, loc="upper left", bbox_to_anchor=(0.125,0.98))
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)
plt.show()
```

Also the reason seems intuitive. Png is a bitmap format, it saves the image as pixels. Pdf is a vector format, it saves the image as vector shapes.

While the png needs to store always the same amount of pixels (~2000x1500 in this case), it will take longer to save png for small `N` (here up to `N=30` or  `NxN = 900`). But the more tiles there are in the figure, the more shapes need to be stored in the pdf, hence it will eventually take longer to save many tiles in pdf format. We assume that the time it takes to save the pdf file is roughly proportionally to the amount of tiles to store. This suggests to have a quadratic relationship of time with `N`, `time ~ N**2`. Fitting a quadratic polynomial to the data and evaluating the polynomial at `t=1000` gives

```
fit = np.polyfit(ns, pdf[:,0], 2)
print( np.poly1d(fit)(1000) )
```

gives 340 seconds, which is 5:40 minutes. This is the estimated time it takes to save the 1000x1000 matrix.

*Note: All data here is produced on an Intel i5 3.5GHz windows computer running python 2.7 and matplotlib 2.1. Using a different computer will of course change the timings.*

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest really appreciate the detailed answer